# Autocorrecting textbox input (vb.net code)

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, textbox

I cant get the following vb.net code too work. What Im trying to achive is to limit the numbers used between and inclusive of 3 and 6. if a user dose enter a value less than 3 that the textbox corrects the value to 3 and if a user enters a value greater than 6 the textbox value is changed to 6...

```
Select Case e.KeyChar
    Case "3", "4", "5", "6", vbBack
        e.Handled = False
    Case Else
        e.Handled = True
        If TextBox27.Text <= 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Minimum of 3 loads permissible", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox27.Text = "3"
            TextBox27.Focus()
        ElseIf TextBox27.Text >= 7 Then
            'Shows error message...
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum of 6 loads permissible", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox27.Text = "6"
            TextBox27.Focus()
        End If

End Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information on the problem would be helpful. Are you getting an exception? I think that you need some quotes around the 2 and 7. Also, the text comparisons (i.e. `TextBox27.Text <= "2"`) might be fooled depending on other code in you application.

```
Select Case e.KeyChar
    Case "3", "4", "5", "6", vbBack
        e.Handled = False
    Case Else
        e.Handled = True
        If TextBox27.Text <= "2" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Minimum of 3 loads permissible", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox27.Text = "3"
            TextBox27.Focus()
        ElseIf TextBox27.Text >= "7" Then
            'Shows error message...
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum of 6 loads permissible", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox27.Text = "6"
            TextBox27.Focus()
        End If

End Select
```

Comment: yeah tried that but I still have the same problem if i type 1 or 2 the textbox responds as expected... however if i type in anything lagrger than 6 the texbox dose not respond..

Comment: That's because `TextBox27.Text >= "7"` is never True. The box only accepts characters that are less than 7. The text comparison that you are making evaluates the alphabetical order. Perhaps you should convert TextBox27.Text to an integer, and then compare to 7 (without the quotes.